# How to match more than one ending character?

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I have a vector of column names of which I would like to extract the ones not ending in **be** using str_match, yet it displays wrong results.

I've tried some regexp to match those endings in **be** like

```r
str_match(names(fa17), '[^(be)$]')
str_match(names(fa17), '[^(b(?=e))]$')
```

and

```r
str_match(names(fa17), '[^(be)]$') %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>% filter(!is.na(V1))
```

with which I get the most near-to-solution approach.

```r
   V1 row
1   o   1
2   d   2
3   a   3
4   a   6
5   o   7
6   o   8
7   o 196
8   a 424
9   a 425
10  a 692
11  n 693
12  o 697
```

but it seems to be choosing only the names not-ending in **e**, not **be**.

Any help, please?

The names vector is the following:

```r
> names(fa17)
  [1] "codigo"         "cli_ced"        "cedula"         "amie"           "c_anoe"         "es_regeva"      "ciclo"          "estado"        
  [9] "indtabe"        "edadcbe"        "sexoabe"        "vinuabe"        "vivfebe"        "vivffbe"        "vivfgbe"        "vivfhbe"       
 [17] "vivfcbe"        "vivfdbe"        "vimaabe"        "vipaabe"        "vixoabe"        "vixaabe"        "txlebbe"        "txmabbe"       
 [25] "txcibbe"        "cuadbbe"        "lapzbbe"        "calcbbe"        "biblbbe"        "libcabe"        "inapabe"        "vamaabe"       
 [33] "llmaabe"        "declabe"        "eprobbe"        "pachabe"        "buclabe"        "macoabe"        "prmoabe"        "mafeabe"       
 [41] "prreabe"        "mamoabe"        "maanabe"        "simpabe"        "presbbe"        "mapaabe"        "maprabe"        "pclaabe"       
 [49] "sinhabe"        "ejclabe"        "tclaabe"        "adclabe"        "propabe"        "mensabe"        "enclabe"        "men1abe"       
 [57] "duclabe"        "apreabe"        "apetnbe"        "prdiabe"        "prexabe"        "proeabe"        "maexabe"        "men2abe"       
 [65] "reexabe"        "repibbe"        "miesabe"        "amcoabe"        "teesabe"        "buesabe"        "soesabe"        "fuesabe"       
 [73] "miprabe"        "htarabe"        "dtarbbe"        "clueabe"        "escrabe"        "ilumabe"        "cespabe"        "prdsbbe"       
 [81] "mleebbe"        "mleibbe"        "mlesbbe"        "mledabe"        "leceabe"        "alecabe"        "clecabe"        "lediabe"       
 [89] "liababe"        "fleeabe"        "fnotabe"        "fcinabe"        "fmusabe"        "fartabe"        "ftvzabe"        "fbibabe"       
 [97] "fdepabe"        "fintabe"        "fsocabe"        "titvbbe"        "tjueabe"        "tintabe"        "tjugabe"        "dllrabe"       
[105] "tcinabe"        "tbibabe"        "tdepabe"        "tvolabe"        "tartabe"        "trabcbe"        "ctraabe"        "patrcbe"       
[113] "caslabe"        "ncioabe"        "inacabe"        "naciabe"        "aniobbe"        "nacmabe"        "nacpabe"        "vimabbe"       
[121] "vipabbe"        "niepcbe"        "niemcbe"        "luzeabe"        "aguaabe"        "desaabe"        "telfabe"        "tvstabe"       
[129] "inteabe"        "basuabe"        "nmtvabe"        "cradabe"        "nmpcabe"        "crefbbe"        "nlavabe"        "ncelbbe"       
[137] "ncelcbe"        "ncarabe"        "piscabe"        "nlibbbe"        "ucombbe"        "ucomcbe"        "ucomdbe"        "ucomebe"       
[145] "ucomfbe"        "inthabe"        "intaabe"        "cfauabe"        "ccybabe"        "cotrabe"        "dupcabe"        "dfpcabe"       
[153] "hupcabe"        "hfpcabe"        "comtabe"        "comjabe"        "comhabe"        "comrabe"        "comiabe"        "comvabe"       
[161] "comnabe"        "fpceabe"        "fpchabe"        "olpcabe"        "upceabe"        "cothabe"        "upcoabe"        "comibbe"       
[169] "comjbbe"        "comrbbe"        "comhbbe"        "comvbbe"        "comtbbe"        "prejabe"        "reprabe"        "matiabe"       
[177] "mestabe"        "vicnabe"        "haexpbe"        "prgrabe"        "prcoabe"        "hrrsdbe"        "hrrscbe"        "etnibbe"       
[185] "leneabe"        "ncalabe"        "idtfabe"        "peclbbe"        "bclaabe"        "emesabe"        "exalabe"        "apoeabe"       
[193] "peesdbe"        "sojuabe"        "roesabe"        "fas_ano"        "txleabe"        "txmaabe"        "txciabe"        "cuadabe"       
[201] "lapzabe"        "calcabe"        "eproabe"        "dtarabe"        "prdsabe"        "trababe"        "patrbbe"        "niembbe"       
[209] "niepbbe"        "nlibabe"        "peclabe"        "lengabe"        "etniabe"        "nhijabe"        "neduabe"        "cdorabe"       
[217] "cescbbe"        "csofabe"        "clibabe"        "clitabe"        "diccabe"        "clavabe"        "dvdqabe"        "ctvcabe"       
[225] "ccamabe"        "cmicabe"        "ncelabe"        "nbanabe"        "intebbe"        "relmabe"        "inmeabe"        "presabe"       
[233] "maayabe"        "reemabe"        "cliabbe"        "roalabe"        "roclabe"        "inclabe"        "espeabe"        "peesabe"       
[241] "ctscabe"        "ctsaabe"        "ctseabe"        "ctsnabe"        "ctstabe"        "moclabe"        "amclabe"        "demaabe"       
[249] "repiabe"        "tescbbe"        "lleebbe"        "hablabe"        "cuidabe"        "inedabe"        "opinabe"        "strsabe"       
[257] "deciabe"        "provabe"        "tdurabe"        "perdabe"        "preqabe"        "cosnabe"        "tmucabe"        "disfabe"       
[265] "afutabe"        "amababe"        "trapabe"        "nervabe"        "geneabe"        "extrbbe"        "dimpabe"        "ayudabe"       
[273] "dfutabe"        "planabe"        "ctrabbe"        "bmatabe"        "dimaabe"        "ematabe"        "fmatabe"        "amatabe"       
[281] "matvabe"        "nmatabe"        "apmaabe"        "umatabe"        "trmaabe"        "hrrsabe"        "tvidabe"        "grrsabe"       
[289] "bdhuabe"        "repicbe"        "extrabe"        "edadebe"        "etnicbe"        "lengbbe"        "ocupabe"        "niepabe"       
[297] "labpabe"        "ocumabe"        "niemabe"        "labmabe"        "trabbbe"        "clapabe"        "cescabe"        "cmp3abe"       
[305] "cboxabe"        "cperabe"        "paslbbe"        "felibbe"        "ptilbbe"        "leobbbe"        "gbibbbe"        "fldeabe"       
[313] "hrleabe"        "mletabe"        "mleoabe"        "fleebbe"        "alecbbe"        "clecbbe"        "ledibbe"        "liabbbe"       
[321] "lecebbe"        "drogbbe"        "bvanbbe"        "bpelbbe"        "tescabe"        "llecabe"        "llebabe"        "llecnbe"       
[329] "lletabe"        "lletpbe"        "lletebe"        "lleaabe"        "lleoabe"        "relmcbe"        "inmebbe"        "maaybbe"       
[337] "reembbe"        "eprocbe"        "maenbbe"        "sinhbbe"        "solcbbe"        "eactabe"        "declbbe"        "reclbbe"       
[345] "buclbbe"        "moclbbe"        "amclbbe"        "peescbe"        "exesbbe"        "inmlabe"        "inclcbe"        "coesabe"       
[353] "saesabe"        "trviabe"        "dmatabe"        "blegabe"        "dileabe"        "bessabe"        "dessabe"        "bcnnabe"       
[361] "dcnnabe"        "gmatabe"        "dihnabe"        "dinaabe"        "dipiabe"        "dimuabe"        "diciabe"        "diteabe"       
[369] "didaabe"        "afutbbe"        "extrcbe"        "segeabe"        "segcabe"        "segpabe"        "seccabe"        "secaabe"       
[377] "nedufbe"        "carrabe"        "viecabe"        "feliabe"        "ptilabe"        "leobabe"        "gbibabe"        "allcabe"       
[385] "capacbe"        "cunoabe"        "enclbbe"        "ensmbbe"        "htarcbe"        "ltrabbe"        "maprbbe"        "men1bbe"       
[393] "mleeabe"        "mleiabe"        "mlesabe"        "nedugbe"        "oreiabe"        "secabbe"        "seccbbe"        "segcbbe"       
[401] "segebbe"        "segpbbe"        "trvibbe"        "ensmabe"        "diskabe"        "injhabe"        "ocujabe"        "ocupebe"       
[409] "ocumebe"        "ocjhabe"        "ocstabe"        "carrbbe"        "tsupabe"        "htardbe"        "expeabe"        "trvicbe"       
[417] "paslabe"        "dicsabe"        "dietabe"        "diecabe"        "didsabe"        "dirfabe"        "ctracbe"        "p_no_respuesta"
[425] "enc_valida"     "tclfabe"        "tpcfabe"        "conadbe"        "tdiscbe"        "gdiscbe"        "cedbhbe"        "nacibbe"       
[433] "tppsabe"        "inacdbe"        "idioabe"        "idiobbe"        "idiocbe"        "idiodbe"        "idioebe"        "idiofbe"       
[441] "idiogbe"        "idiohbe"        "idioibe"        "idiojbe"        "idiokbe"        "idiolbe"        "idiombe"        "idionbe"       
[449] "idioobe"        "idieabe"        "idiebbe"        "idiecbe"        "idiedbe"        "idieebe"        "idiefbe"        "idiegbe"       
[457] "caslbbe"        "nmpeabe"        "vivfsbe"        "vivfybe"        "vivfjbe"        "vivsabe"        "nhijbbe"        "jhogabe"       
[465] "niepfbe"        "niemfbe"        "esjhabe"        "escmabe"        "escpabe"        "actpabe"        "actmabe"        "niessbe"       
[473] "nsegabe"        "tpviabe"        "pardabe"        "cuarbbe"        "nducabe"        "tshgabe"        "cuarpbe"        "cocqbbe"       
[481] "nmicabe"        "nvcaabe"        "clapbbe"        "imprbbe"        "cboxbbe"        "veccabe"        "uintabe"        "ucorabe"       
[489] "rredabe"        "lcliabe"        "nlibcbe"        "tesccbe"        "dccarbe"        "psbcabe"        "preuabe"        "ovocabe"       
[497] "atrsabe"        "inasabe"        "faltabe"        "rabuabe"        "rabubbe"        "rabucbe"        "rabudbe"        "rabuebe"       
[505] "rabufbe"        "rabugbe"        "rabuhbe"        "rabuibe"        "rabujbe"        "rabukbe"        "rabulbe"        "rabumbe"       
[513] "rabunbe"        "rabuobe"        "rabupbe"        "prdscbe"        "roalbbe"        "buesbbe"        "amocbbe"        "buclcbe"       
[521] "scamabe"        "eactbbe"        "inciabe"        "inapbbe"        "vamabbe"        "llmabbe"        "tclabbe"        "mahcbbe"       
[529] "cliadbe"        "declcbe"        "mledbbe"        "ppeebbe"        "aytacbe"        "fnotbbe"        "fcinbbe"        "fvisbbe"       
[537] "prculbe"        "fartbbe"        "fbibdbe"        "fdepbbe"        "fsocbbe"        "flclabe"        "flcaabe"        "factabe"       
[545] "posiabe"        "srecabe"        "trsfabe"        "estrabe"        "ayuoabe"        "emptabe"        "disfbbe"        "perdbbe"       
[553] "soceabe"        "hrtvabe"        "hramabe"        "hrdpabe"        "hrvlabe"        "hrarabe"        "tleebbe"        "dllrcbe"       
[561] "hrlacbe"        "hrpeabe"        "lpoeabe"        "lartabe"        "dgpibbe"        "amabbbe"        "oppsabe"        "provbbe"       
[569] "ayudbbe"        "decibbe"        "cuidbbe"        "tdurbbe"        "tmucbbe"        "inedbbe"        "refuabe"        "movhabe"       
[577] "movhbbe"        "movhcbe"        "movhdbe"        "movhebe"        "movhfbe"        "movhgbe"        "movhhbe"        "movhibe"       
[585] "tmovabe"        "pmovabe"        "momoabe"        "pmpvabe"        "isocbbe"        "bpelcbe"        "agrsabe"        "intrbbe"       
[593] "hvecabe"        "bvancbe"        "brobabe"        "bahmabe"        "robybbe"        "emailbe"        "hambabe"        "sticabe"       
[601] "eticabe"        "ptecabe"        "tuniabe"        "reppabe"        "repsabe"        "repmabe"        "prdibbe"        "prexbbe"       
[609] "proebbe"        "men2bbe"        "propbbe"        "aprebbe"        "mticabe"        "mensbbe"        "rperabe"        "connabe"       
[617] "mdudabe"        "mdudbbe"        "mdudcbe"        "mduddbe"        "mdudebe"        "mdudfbe"        "mdudgbe"        "mdudhbe"       
[625] "mdudibe"        "ldudabe"        "ldudbbe"        "ldudcbe"        "lduddbe"        "ldudebe"        "ldudfbe"        "ldudgbe"       
[633] "ldudhbe"        "ldudibe"        "edudabe"        "edudbbe"        "edudcbe"        "eduddbe"        "edudebe"        "edudfbe"       
[641] "edudgbe"        "edudhbe"        "edudibe"        "cdudabe"        "cdudbbe"        "cdudcbe"        "cduddbe"        "cdudebe"       
[649] "cdudfbe"        "cdudgbe"        "cdudhbe"        "cdudibe"        "acopabe"        "atemabe"        "atecabe"        "plesbbe"       
[657] "plmebbe"        "entlbbe"        "rtxtbbe"        "cncpbbe"        "binfbbe"        "rsitbbe"        "rpalabe"        "iadiabe"       
[665] "rmatbbe"        "hupcbbe"        "hfpccbe"        "hfpcbbe"        "comvcbe"        "comrcbe"        "comjcbe"        "comhdbe"       
[673] "prejbbe"        "comicbe"        "comoabe"        "artiabe"        "cultabe"        "depiabe"        "sociabe"        "blylabe"       
[681] "matgabe"        "amdoabe"        "prmobbe"        "prrebbe"        "feldabe"        "maanbbe"        "ecivbbe"        "inacfbe"       
[689] "idieibe"        "injhbbe"        "ocstbbe"        "carga"          "poblacion"      "etniebe"        "cesccbe"        "ceduabe"       
[697] "cuestionario"
```

Comment: `x[!grepl("be$", x)]`

Comment: What you wanted to write is `(?<!be)$`